# iPhone app crashes before memory warning event

Tags: iphone, crash, memory-warning

The app crashes because of memory overhead, but applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning event doesn't raise in time. (I know exactly that the reason of crash is low memory because it crashes on resources loading and there is no corresponding crash report, and XCode doesn't break debugging, app silently quits to springboard).

So I'm looking for some method how to prevent this overhead. Maybe there is a function or instrument that gives amount of available memory?

Comment: So there are no bad access warnings?  The app just quits?  What are you loading that is so big?  More info about your project is needed, but my guess would be that there is no reason to load everything at once like this.

Comment: If your resource loading is done sequentially within one method on the main thread, it will block the main thread and prevent your application from receiving applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning, which is why you aren't seeing that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020327/how-to-find-available-memory-in-iphone-programmatically

Comment: Brad, Robert, thank you for answers. It's enough to decide what to do to solve the problem. James, I'm loading textures for game, using classical scenario: read all handlers from file and load all resources in one init method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in link by Robert Harvey:

```
#import <mach/mach.h>
#import <mach/mach_host.h>

+(natural_t) get_free_memory {
mach_port_t host_port;
mach_msg_type_number_t host_size;
vm_size_t pagesize;
host_port = mach_host_self();
host_size = sizeof(vm_statistics_data_t) / sizeof(integer_t);
host_page_size(host_port, &pagesize);
vm_statistics_data_t vm_stat;
if (host_statistics(host_port, HOST_VM_INFO, (host_info_t)&vm_stat, &host_size) != KERN_SUCCESS) {
NSLog(@"Failed to fetch vm statistics");
return 0;
}
/* Stats in bytes */
natural_t mem_free = vm_stat.free_count * pagesize;
return mem_free;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run it in instruments (allocations) and capture a shot of the heap before and after.