# How can I discover the amount of free memory in iOS?

Tags: ios

How can I discover the amount of free memory in iOS?

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish? And how exactly do you define "free" memory? Since the OS can evict other processes at will, depending on what is needed, the right answer depends on your use case.

Comment: Possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020327/how-to-find-available-memory-in-iphone-programmatically

Comment: possible duplicate of [Available memory for iPhone OS app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798638/available-memory-for-iphone-os-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (uint64_t)getFreeDiskspace
{
uint64_t totalSpace = 0;
uint64_t totalFreeSpace = 0;

__autoreleasing error = nil;  
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];  

if (dictionary) {  
    NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];  
    NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
    totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
    totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
    NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu MiB with %llu MiB Free memory available.", ((totalSpace/1024ll)/1024ll), ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll));
} else {  
    NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@, Code = %d", [error domain], [error code]);  
}  

return totalFreeSpace;
}
```

This is working

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
natural_t  freeMemory(void) {
    mach_port_t           host_port = mach_host_self();
    mach_msg_type_number_t   host_size = sizeof(vm_statistics_data_t) / sizeof(integer_t);
    vm_size_t               pagesize;
    vm_statistics_data_t     vm_stat;

    host_page_size(host_port, &pagesize);

    if (host_statistics(host_port, HOST_VM_INFO, (host_info_t)&vm_stat, &host_size) != KERN_SUCCESS) NSLog(@"Failed to fetch vm statistics");

    natural_t   mem_used = (vm_stat.active_count + vm_stat.inactive_count + vm_stat.wire_count) * pagesize;
    natural_t   mem_free = vm_stat.free_count * pagesize;
    natural_t   mem_total = mem_used + mem_free;

    return mem_free;
}
```

I'm not claiming credit for this code; I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798638/available-memory-for-iphone-os-app).

Hope this helps!