# Storage usage in iOS, objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-storage

Can anyone tell me, how to get disk storage used amount in Objective-C (ex. music - 1Gb, images - 100Mb, ..., free space - 5Gb)?

UPD: 
I wrote this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary* fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:@"/"error:&error];
unsigned long long freeSpace = [[fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] longLongValue];
unsigned long long totalSpace = [[fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSystemSize] longLongValue];
msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"free disk space: %dGB\n total disk space: %dGB", (int)(freeSpace / (1024*1024*1024)),(int)(totalSpace / (1024*1024*1024))];
```

But i actually need all info, about music, video, etc... like system info about disk (screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/1Y3Q3N1U3Q3A)

Comment: Does anyone know if the freeSpace obtained via NSFileManager mean the space that the app CAN actually use?  I need to have some indication of how many more documents my user can download through my app.

Answer (score 4):

There is no SDCard in iPhone like android. Your application is running its own sandbox . So there is no access outside the sandbox . So think it is not possible .

Comment: What about system info? Settings > general > usage > storage ? There is no access to it, is it?

Comment: @a-rukin:please send me some links.

Comment: @a-rukin:Yes ,your above code working .But how you gone get individual size for the images,videos etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not for exactly what you want as V-Xtreme have defined, But Following links

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173768/how-to-print-current-memory-size-in-my-app
- [How to find available memory in iPhone programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020327/how-to-find-available-memory-in-iphone-programmatically)
- http://adeem.me/blog/2009/04/01/get-the-amount-of-free-memory-available/
- To get Available RAM : http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/iphone/Determining_Available_Memory.20081203.html